# Writing a proper regex to allow number and only combinations of letters and numbers mixed up

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc, boolean

I have a string example which looks like this:

```
51925120851209567
```

The length of the string and numbers may vary, however I want to only enable the string to contain just either numbers, or for it to be a combination of letters and numbers. For example a valid one would be something like this:

```
B0031Y4M8S // contains combination of letters and numbers without white space
```

Invalid regex would be:

```
Does not apply // this one contains white spaces and has only letters
```

To summarize things up, the regex should allow only these combinations:

```
51925120851209567 // contains only numbers and is valid

B0031Y4M8S // contains combination of numbers and letters and is valid as well
```

Everything else is invalid...

The current solution that I have covers only for the string to be a set of integers and nothing else... However I'm not really sure how to filter out combination of numbers and letters without white spaces and special charachters to be valid as well for the regex?

```
Regex regex = new Regex("^[0-9]+$");

    if (regex.IsMatch(parameter))
    { 
     // allow if statement to pass if the regex matches
    }
```

Can someone help me out ?

Comment: Try `"^(?![A-Za-z]+$)[0-9A-Za-z]+$"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Genius, it works like a charm !! =D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?![A-Za-z]+$)[0-9A-Za-z]+$
```

It matches 1+ alphanumeric chars but will fail a match if all string consists of just letters.

**Details**

- `^` - start of a string
- `(?![A-Za-z]+$)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are 1+ ASCII letters followed with the end of string immediately to the right of the current location
- `[0-9A-Za-z]+` - 1+ ASCII letters
- `$` - end of string.

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f!%5bA-Za-z%5d%2b%5cr%3f%24%29%5b0-9A-Za-z%5d%2b%5cr%3f%24&i=51925120851209567%0d%0a+%2f%2f+contains+only+numbers+and+is+valid%0d%0aB0031Y4M8S%0d%0a+%2f%2f+contains+combination+of+numbers+and+letters+and+is+valid+as+well%0d%0aASDFFDSSDFGG&o=m).

Answer (score 0):

**@The fourth bird**'s answer will almost get you there. I'm no regex expert, but an easy way to get you what you want would be to use:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
```

This will get you the first level of exclusion. If it passes that, then check with:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z]+$");
```

If it matches that, then you know it's only alphabetical characters and you can skip it. I'm sure there's a better way to code golf this one out, but this should work for now if you're in a crunch.

Comment: You shouldn't have to use two regular expressions to check something like this.